# Outlook 365: transfer incoming emails but not spam

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I have a professional mailbox that I can access through the web version of outlook 365. I configured it to transfer all incoming e-mails to my second mailbox.

The problem is that the first mailbox receives (and recognizes) a lot of spam and transfers it to my second mailbox.

Is it possible in outlook 365 to configure transfer of all incoming letters ignoring those recognized as spam?

Comment: Why is recognised spam going to your inbox in the first place? That's what the spam folder is for…. https://i.stack.imgur.com/We9JL.png

Comment: I don't know why :) I receive transferred message to my second mail box and I see in it the spam folder of the first one (I've configured to keep a copy).